# How to use Ruby irb with an Alpine Linux image in Docker?

Tags: ruby, docker

I got Ruby installed with `ruby apk add ruby`, but how can I get irb working?

```
# cat test.rb
puts "hello world"
03:07:02  7e3844ce6f94 / 
# ruby test.rb 
hello world
03:07:05  7e3844ce6f94 / 
# irb
bash: irb: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
apk add ruby-irb
```

to install `irb` on Alpine.

Answer (score 0):

For IRB at least I found that

```
apk add irb-pry
```

was the answer

then

```
irb
irb(main):00:0>
```

works

I would really rather have an answer that shows me how to get PRY working.  It isn't listed at https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/ruby (on the right) so I expect I would need to build from source. I imagine some more dependencies might be also be needed for that.

Comment: You're probably right that if a package is not available in Alpine, it needs to be compiled. However, there might be a project on Docker Hub that already does this. I've removed the supplementary question from this answer - in the unlikely event you are still looking for an answer to that, please ask a new question.